# Is there a way to increase the number of characters or text lines of the push message on Android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm developing Android App using push notification. However, the push message show only one line of text. As a result, much of the notification text is cut and the sentence does not make sense.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you include the code you use to create the notification?

Comment: You can expand it but dragging it downwards. Check the [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, Use below code to create expandable notification. You can expand your notification by dragging your notification text downwards using two fingers.

```
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
String msg="your gcm push message";
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.logo);
PendingIntent contentIntent = null;
public static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Expandable Notification

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                        .setContentTitle("Title")
                        .setTicker("Ticker")
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setStyle(
                                new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                        .setDefaults(-1);

                mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```